# choose the correct option that following series converge uniformly?

Tags: real-analysis

> Choose  the  correct option that  following series converge uniformly?
>
> a) $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (a_n\cos nt + b_n \sin nt)$$ over the interval $[-\pi,\pi] $ where $\sum_{n=n}|a_n| < \infty$ and $\sum_{n=n}|b_n| < \infty$
>
> b) $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} e^{-nx}\cos nx$ over the interval $(0,\infty)$

## My attempt:

For option $b)$ Take  a sequence $x_n = 1/n$ to find $f_n(x_n) = e^{-1} \cos(1) \neq 0$. so the$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} e^{-nx}\cos nx$  is not uniform converge on $(0, \infty)$

For  a) take $ t =-\pi$ i got $f_n(t_n)= (a_n \cos nt + b_n\sin nt)= a_n\cos n(-\pi) + b_n\sin n(-\pi))=an$

so$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (a_n\cos nt + b_n\sin nt)$ is also not  uniformly  convergent on $[-\pi,\pi]$

But  my professor  said that  option a) is correct    i don't  understand  how  it is correct ??

Any hints/solution will be appreciated

thank u

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For 1) it is enough to observe that
$$
\sup_{t\in\mathbb{R}} |a_n \cos(nt) + b_n \sin(nt)| \leq |a_n| + |b_n| =: M_n
$$
and use [Weierstrass' M-test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_M-test) to get uniform convergence of the series.

Comment: but here  $a_n  \neq  0$  and $b_n \neq 0$ ?? how can u say that

Comment: Since $\sum_n M_n < \infty$ (being $\sum_n |a_n|$ and $\sum_n |b_n|$ convergent by assumption), then you can use Weierstrass' test.

Comment: Even if that happens, it does not affect the convergence.

Comment: @Rigel..thanks ..